# NCO concatenate hourly to daily output

Tags: concatenation, nco

I'm very new to NCO. The tool looks powerful to me but I'm still a bit confused about the syntax. I want to concatenate model data from a 3-hourly output to daily netCDF files. I want to loop over year, month and day. E.g., input files in netCDF format:

```
$year-$month-$day_00:00:00
$year-$month-$day_03:00:00
$year-$month-$day_06:00:00
...
```

output file should be:

```
$year-$month-$day
```

Is there a simple solution for this in combination with the `ncrcat` command?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to provide us code that you have tried, what is failing, etc., before others can help.

Comment: I would upvote the previous comment if I knew how. Also, there is an NCO  manual :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was lazy and did not have much time, therefore I did not read the manual in the very first beginning... Nevertheless, I found a very simple solution - I only had to build a loop iterating over year, month and day and then applying ncrcat:

```
ncrcat $year-$month-$day* $year-$month-$day
```

I simply needed to add the Asterisk for summing up all the output files for one day.

Kind regards